# How to open js file as content file in NuGet package

Tags: visual-studio, dependencies, nuget-package

I made a package of an empty class library project in visual studio. there is a folder at the root directory named "js" which contains js files with build action "Content" as well as being copied to output directory.

My goal is: In the project where this package will be installed, I want to be able to open the file and see it's content during development. I can see that the file is present in the folder "content file" in the dependencies view, but I can't open it to at least view it's content. How can I make the content of the file visible to the developers? I can't find anything regarding this in the documentation. Did I miss something? What am I doing wrong?

This file will be used as a static js file to link in web pages.

I am new at making packages and so my knowledge is limited on the subject. Any advice will be appreciated.